# Running total vertically - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset:

[image]

If I were to create a payment inflow matrix per a cohort where payment created_date is in columns and created date formatted as a cohort is in rows, it will look like:

[image]

I need to calculate running total per a column - see below:

[image]

There could be other fields in the table, e.g. product type which should influence running total.

I've seen the standard solution with = calculate(sum([X]), all(table), [date]<=max[date]) but I cannot make it work. What am I doing wrong? .pbix is uploaded at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E3qJyOv11xSOlVRHAL9uq2C1Zho-g3zc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of Power BI's build-in **Quick measures**:

[image]

This will give you the following result:

[image]

However, you won't get any aggregation for Jan and Feb since there are no according records in 2022-2. It looks like created_q is actually order_q?

When this is important, you would have to add dummy zero amounts with 2022-2 order_date.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I guess the catch here is that I need to extend the values till the end - see the end-result table.

Comment: Exactly. I already added this to my answer.